# Why am I getting SytaxError in modules.js while running METEOR?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am getting the following error when I start meteor. It was working fine on my old machine but not working now.

```
W20190918-11:37:00.641(5)? (STDERR) /home/waqas/Documents/code-base/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/modules.js:3284
W20190918-11:37:00.644(5)? (STDERR)             ...this._options,
W20190918-11:37:00.645(5)? (STDERR)             ^^^
W20190918-11:37:00.645(5)? (STDERR)           
W20190918-11:37:00.645(5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
W20190918-11:37:00.645(5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20190918-11:37:00.646(5)? (STDERR)     at /home/waqas/Documents/code-base/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:287:30
W20190918-11:37:00.646(5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20190918-11:37:00.646(5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/waqas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_3.1ujjc8o.xamr++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20190918-11:37:00.647(5)? (STDERR)     at /home/waqas/Documents/code-base/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
```

**I am using this command to start meteor:** 
`meteor run --port 4000 --settings .config/development/settings.json` (even it is not working with meteor command)

**Versions:**
`Meteor 1.4.1.3`
`node: v10.16.3`
`npm 6.9.0`

Comment: We clearly lack of information here. Post the code that generated the error and give us some context if you want to be helped

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a heads up that this question doesn't meet the quality guidelines of SO because it's unclear, and doesn't show an effort to solve the issue yourself. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I've answered anyway as a gesture of goodwill, but be aware that other SO users may downvote questions like this. Cheers!

Comment: I suppose either a missing `meteor npm insall` or the `ecma` package is either missing in `.meteor/packages` or in the `package.js` of one of the packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor doesn't compile/transpile files in the `node_modules` directory by default, so if there is code which is not supported by the bundled version of node (currently `8.15.1`), it will throw a `SyntaxError`.

To fix this, you can tell Meteor that you want to compile that module by symlinking it into your project, at which point the compiler will think it's part of the main project and compile it for you.

Alternatively, depending on the module, you can import a pre-compiled version inside the module directly. For example `import 'example-module/dist/example.min.js'`

I can't tell you if that would work for your project because you haven't provided enough detail

---

Edit: Looking at the [feature compatibility table for node](https://node.green), rest/spread syntax `...` is supported in node 8 so it might be something else strange going on.

Can you provide more details, including Meteor version, how you are running it and the node modules you are using?

---

Edit 2:

Thanks for posting your Meteor version. Meteor 1.4.1.3 comes [bundled with Node 4.6.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v1413-2016-10-21), which looking at those tables again, show that it does not support rest/spread. In which case the symlinking strategy should not be needed as I believe node_modules used to be compiled by 1.4.

Do you have a `.babelrc` file in your project?
And can you check which node module contains the problem syntax?
(Check this file: `/home/waqas/Documents/code-base/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/modules.js:3284` and see if you can find which module is inlined there)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question and added more details. kindly check it

Comment: @waqasMumtaz, thanks. I've updated the answer a bit further. At least we know why the `...` syntax is failing, it's supposed to! Now we just need to figure out why it's in the output

Comment: thanks a lot, after paying attention to versions, I fixed my problem. Thanks once again.

Solution: working with `node v8.12.0`